# Potential Field navigation implementation in ROS?

Tags: ros, navigation, simulation, stage, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At Player/Stage, I often used [VFH](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Player-2.0.0/player/group__driver__vfh.html), a potential field navigation means. However, I have not really come across any potential field driver implementation at ROS. Has anyone attempted to do so ? Can VFH be ported in to ROS ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12151/potential-field-navigation-implementation-in-ros-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A very simple implementation of potential fields is available [here](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=potential_fields). You can use it for inspiration. AFAIK there is no VFH implemented in ROS (people seem to prefer the dynamic window approach), but it shouldn't be hard to port the Player implementation in ROS. A Player wrapper is provided in the same repository.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-11-29**:
Unfortunately not, but I will be glad to help you if you have any problem-question. Just post a ROS question and maybe send me an email with the link so you can be sure I'll reply. Good luck!

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-11-29**:
@Lorenzo Riano : Is there any Tutorial Page for the package ?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-11-29**:
@Lorenzo Riano : Thank you ! ..... just that I am yet not great writing wrappers ! .... :)

**Comment by [fantabulum](https://answers.ros.org/users/25961/fantabulum/) on 2016-02-25**:
Link is broken